# Ruby on Rails flash messages in French

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, utf-8, localization, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Working on a rails app in French, however whenever i include an accent on the flash messages it  breaks the site.

For example

```
format.html {redirect_to @message.annonce, notice:"Votre message a été envoyé"}
format.html {redirect_to @message.annonce, notice:"Votre email n'a pas pu être envoyer à cause d'une erreur."}
```

my config/application.rb looks like this

```
 config.i18n.default_locale = :fr
 config.encoding = "utf-8"
```

How does one do about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add `# encoding: UTF-8` as the first line of your file to add accent in it.

If this is not working please give us the exception raised.